# $\mathbf{f}:M\to\mathbb{R^n}$ continuous iff the inverse image of all closed subsets of $\mathbb{R^m}$ under f is closed subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am preparing for my exam and therefore am practicing by doing some exercises. I need help with the following one.

> Let M be nonempty, closed subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbf{f}:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$: Show $\mathbf{f}:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is continuous if and only for every closed subset S of $\mathbb{R^m}$, $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^n}.$

I already proved this: Let M be nonempty, open subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbf{f}:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$: Show $\mathbf{f}:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is continuous if and only for every open subset S of $\mathbb{R^m}$, $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}.$

And I wanted to use it for this task. But I guess its only working if we are working with $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$. Here we are working with a subset $M\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$.

This is what I have: Since S is closed, $\mathbb{R^m}$\S is open. Thus $\mathbf{f}^{-1}$[$\mathbb{R^m}$\S] is open.

And here is the problem... if we would have $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$, we would have $\mathbf{f}^{-1}$[$\mathbb{R^m}$\S]=$\mathbb{R^n}$\ $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ is open and thus the complement $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ is closed.

But our domain is not $\mathbb{R^n}$ instead we have the subset M. Thats why $\mathbf{f}^{-1}$[$\mathbb{R^m}$\S]=M\ $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ and $\mathbf{f}^{-1}$[$\mathbb{R^m}$\S]$\neq$$\mathbb{R^n}$\ $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$. So I thought I could do this. Since $M$\ $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ is open, the complement $M^c\cup$$\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ is closed. We know $M^c$ is open. Thats why $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ can't be open because the union would be open then. I thought I got it know and I could say that the inverse image is closed. But no... the inverse image could be neither open nor closed...right?

Thats why I am stuck now. Is there even a possibility to prove it like that. Or does the fact that we are working with a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ destroy the possibility of concluding the lemma from my previous proof with open sets.

Is there anyone who could help me out? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Should the block quote read "Let M be a nonempty, closed subset..."? Also, what definition of continuity are you working with? One reasonable definition is that the preimage of a closed set is closed, in which case this exercise is just about knowing that the closed subsets of a closed subspace are closed in the entire space

Comment: What you proved already seems equally suspect. What if $M$ has no interior? How could $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ be open in $\Bbb{R}^n$ (unless it were empty)? The usual correction would be to say $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ is open in $M$ instead, meaning that $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ is the intersection of $M$ with an open set. I would correct the current exercise similarly.

Comment: @stillconfused Yeah you were right I mistyped. The definition of continuity does not play any role in this question. I wanted to proof this lemma by concluding it from the lemma with open sets.

Comment: @TheoBendit I don't quite understand. I didn't say that $f^{-1}[S]$ is open in $\mathbb{R^n}$. But yes it is my goal to prove it. What do you mean with "correct the current exercise similarly". This is the exercise I got and I have to prove that $f^{-1}[S]$ is open in $\mathbb{R^n}$. My problem is if $\mathbb{R^n}$ would be my domain instead of the subset M....we could easily prove it. So either I overlook something or you can't do this analogously..

Comment: @Analysis_Mark I'm referring to your first paragraph under the question (in the block-quote). You said that you already proved a characterisation of continuity involving open sets. What I'm saying is, that characterisation is actually false. For example, if $M$ is a singleton $\{x\}$ in, say, $\Bbb{R}^2$, then any function $f$ from from it is continuous, and is constant. If we let $y = f(x)$, then $f^{-1}[\{y\}] = \{x\}$, which is *not* open in $\Bbb{R}^2$! Basically, the problem you've seen before suffers from an analogous issue to the problem in front of you now.

Comment: @Analysis_Mark What I'm suggesting is replace "open in $\Bbb{R}^n$ in your original problem with "open in $M$". In your new problem, replace "closed in $\Bbb{R}^n$" with "closed in $M$", which means there is a closed set $C \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ such that your set $f^{-1}[S]$ is equal to $C \cap M$. This will make the result true!

Comment: @TheoBendit, the assumption in the first paragraph under the block quote is that $M$ is open, so $M = \{x\}$ isn't allowed by hypothesis.

Comment: @TheoBendit But I can't do that haha. Thats the task of my professor and I am sure that these taske are completely perfect.

Comment: @Analysis_Mark No, stillconfused pointed out what I was missing. If $M$ is open, then the statement is perfectly correct, but I think you'll struggle to use that result to prove the new result. You might have to develop a new proof. I would try using sequential continuity, rather than $\varepsilon$-$\delta$, when dealing with closed sets like this.

Comment: @TheoBendit Hm yeah okay. I thought that maybe theres a lemma like if the union of two sets is closed iff the two sets are closed. Or something like that... or that the union of a closed set and a set that is neither open nor closed can't be closed...

Comment: The problem is: You simply cannot use your already proved part for open sets, because you would need $f$ to be defined on an open set. However, $M$ is not necessarily open.

Comment: @Analysis_Mark If I understand, the statement that you are hoping for is: $M^c \cup f^{-1}(S)$ is closed if and only if $f^{-1}(S)$ is closed. This won't happen. Take $M = [0,1]$, $f^{-1}(S) = [1/4,3/4]$. Then $f^{-1}(S)$ is closed, but $M^c \cup f^{-1}(S)$ is not closed.

Comment: @sranthrop Why not. I have S being closed, thus I have $\mathbb{R^m}$ \S. We then can conclude that f^{-1}[$\mathbb{R^m}$ \S] is open.

Comment: @stillconfused I don't  need an if and only-statement....Just that $M^c\cup f^{-1}(S)$ being closed and $M^c$ being closed implies $f^{-1}(S)$ is closed.

Comment: No. Your statement says: If $f$ is a function defined on an open set $M$, then $f$ is continuous if and only if preimages of sets open in $\mathbb R^m$ are open in $\mathbb R^n$. But your function is defined on the closed set $M$, and for this situation your statement is not applicable.

Comment: @sranthrop Yeah I see you are totally right. If we would have $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ then we could do this, but not in this case.

Comment: Exactly. Therefore, I also think that another way towards a solution of your exercise is needed, and indeed, when dealing with closed sets sequences are often a good choice :)

Comment: @sranthrop Well if thats the case, I am more overwhelmed with this task than I thought. It is strange that I can't find this kind of task anywhere. There are lots of posted approaches for functions with the domain being a topological space, but for functions with a domain that is a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ you can't find anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now for an actual answer! As I said in the comments, I would abandon the other exercise, for it's not quite powerful enough to help you, and instead try to prove this with sequential continuity. That is, we will assume that:

> $f : M \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$ is continuous if and only if, given any $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in M$ that converges to $x \in M$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ in $\Bbb{R}^m$.

Now, let's suppose that $f$ is (sequentially) continuous, and $S \subseteq \Bbb{R}^m$ is closed. Further, take $(x_n) \in f^{-1}[S]$, converging to some $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$. We wish to show $x \in f^{-1}[S]$.

Since $f^{-1}[S] \subseteq M$, which is closed, we conclude that $x \in M$, so at least $f(x)$ makes sense. By sequential continuity, we know that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. As $(x_n) \in f^{-1}[S]$, we have $f(x_n) \in S$. Since $S$ is closed, the limit $f(x)$ must also lie in $S$, which means that $x \in f^{-1}[S]$. This proves $f^{-1}[S]$ is closed, as required.

Inversely, suppose $f$ is not continuous. Then, some $(x_n) \in M$ exists, converging to $x \in M$, so that $f(x_n) \not\to f(x)$. We know that a subsequence of $(f(x_n))$ lies some positive distance $\varepsilon$ from $f(x)$. So, by replacing $x_n$ with this subsequence, assume without loss of generality that $\|f(x_n) - f(x)\| > \varepsilon$ for all $n$.

Let $S$ be the closure of the set $\{f(x_n) : n \in \Bbb{N}\}$. As $f(x)$ lies $\varepsilon > 0$ distance from all points in this set, we have $f(x) \notin S$, hence $x \notin f^{-1}[S]$. However, each $x_n$ lies in $f^{-1}[S]$, and the sequence converges to $x$, proving that $f^{-1}[S]$ is not closed. Thus, $f$ does not have the closed set property, completing the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain why $f : M \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$ is continuous if and only if, given any $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in M$ that converges to $x \in M$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ in $\Bbb{R}^m$ is the same as the lemma Let M be nonempty, closed subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbf{f}:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$: Show $\mathbf{f}:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is continuous if and only for every closed subset S of $\mathbb{R^m}$, $\mathbf{f}^{-1}[S]$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^n}?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark I'm not sure I follow what you're asking for here. It seems like you're asking me to explain why sequential continuity is equivalent to this closed set property, but this is literally the one and only point of the answer! Was there a particular step or assumption that you wanted me to elucidate?

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. I thought you took my lemma and phrased it diffierently. I understand it know thats the definition for sequential continuity

Comment: @Analysis_Mark No problem. I don't mean to sound unfriendly in any way. Please feel free to ask me more questions if there's anything else you're not sure about.

Comment: I wanted to know if we should differentiate between $f^{-1}[S]$ being empty when proofing both directions.

Comment: @Analysis_Mark I had the same thought while typing it. It's not necessary; everything I wrote is vacuously true with $M = \emptyset$. It's not difficult to treat separately though, if you think it makes the proof more convincing.

Comment: Okay well thanks. Your answer was pretty clear and I understood everything. But I think you did one small mistake. You wrote that $(x_n)\in f^{-1}[S]$ is converging to a point $\mathbf{x}$$\in\mathbb{R^m}$. Shouldn't this be $\mathbb{R^n}$ or does this make no difference at all?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark You're right: that was an error, and I've fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer, but it's far too long for a comment. I thought I'd just flesh out what I was talking about in the comments.

Your observation that these concepts should be connected is astute, but the two problems are unfortunately too limited to be actually equivalent. As I said in the comments, there is a more general form which makes this equivalence plain (and the proof is what you outlined above, with some trivial adjustments). Given $f : M \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$, then the following are true:

> 1. $f$ is continuous if and only if, given any **open** $S \subseteq \Bbb{R}^m$, the set $f^{-1}[S]$ is **open in $M$**, meaning that there exists some open set $U \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $f^{-1}[S] = U \cap M$, and
> 2. $f$ is continuous if and only if, given any **closed** $S \subseteq \Bbb{R}^m$, the set $f^{-1}[S]$ is **closed in $M$**, meaning that there exists some closed set $C \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $f^{-1}[S] = C \cap M$.

Note: these generalise the problems at hand. If $M$ is open, then $U \cap M$ is also open. If $M$ is closed, then $C \cap M$ is also closed. But, these statements also hold without additional assumptions on $M$.

Also, we can easily show 1 and 2 are equivalent with a proof similar to what you've written. Indeed, the closed and open properties are easily seen to be equivalent.

> If $f$ has the open property and $S \subseteq \Bbb{R}^m$ is closed, then $T = \Bbb{R}^m \setminus S$ is open. Therefore, $f^{-1}[T]$ is open in $M$, i.e. some $U \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ exists such that $f^{-1}[T] = U \cap M$. Thus,
> \begin{align*}
> f^{-1}[S] &= f^{-1}[\Bbb{R}^m \setminus T] = M \setminus f^{-1}[T] \\
> &= M \setminus (U \cap M) = M \setminus U = M \cap (\Bbb{R}^n \setminus U).
> \end{align*}
> Note that $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus U$ is closed, as $U$ is open, proving $f^{-1}[S]$ is closed in $M$.

The converse follows similarly: just swap the words "closed" and "open" in the above proof. To prove 1, the proof will be (I imagine) very similar to whatever the solution was to your previous exercise:

> Suppose $f$ is continuous, $U \subseteq \Bbb{R}^m$ is open, and $x \in f^{-1}[U]$. Then $y := f(x) \in U$, which is open, so a ball of some radius $\varepsilon_x > 0$, centred at $y$, exists inside $U$ (which we'll denote $B(y; \varepsilon_x)$). Using continuity, there is some $\delta_x > 0$ such that
> $$\|z - x\| < \delta_x \text{ and } z \in M \implies \|f(z) - f(x)\| < \varepsilon_x.$$
> Put another way,
> $$B(x; \delta_x) \cap M \subseteq f^{-1}[B(y; \varepsilon_x)] \subseteq f^{-1}[U].$$
> So, performing this for each $x \in f^{-1}[U]$,
> $$\left(\bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}[U]} B(x; \delta_x)\right) \cap M = \bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}[U]} (B(x; \delta_x) \cap M) \subseteq f^{-1}[U].$$
> But, each $x \in f^{-1}[U]$ clearly lies in the left hand side (note: $f^{-1}[U] \subseteq M$), so the $\subseteq$ is, in fact, $=$. The union of the balls is open, so we have shown $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $M$.
>
> Conversely, suppose $f$ has the open set property. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x_0 \in M$. Let $S = B(f(x_0); \varepsilon)$, which is an open set in $\Bbb{R}^m$. Then $f(x) \in S \implies x \in f^{-1}[S]$. The latter is open in $M$, so there exists some open $U \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $x \in f^{-1}[S] = M \cap U$. As $U$ is open, some $\delta > 0$ exists such that $B(x; \delta) \subseteq U$. Thus,
> $$B(x; \delta) \cap M \subseteq M \cap U = f^{-1}[S]$$
> Thus,
> $$\|z - x\| < \delta \text{ and } z \in M \implies f(z) \in S = B(f(x); \varepsilon) \implies \|f(z) - f(x)\| < \varepsilon,$$
> proving continuity.

A note: these characterisations of continuity are the definitions of continuity in terms of topology. The terms "open/closed in $M$" are the meaning of open/closed in the subspace topology of $M$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If $f$ has the open property and $S \subseteq \Bbb{R}^m$ is closed, then $T = \Bbb{R}^m \setminus S$ is open. Therefore, $f^{-1}[T]$ is open in $M$, i.e. some $U \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ exists such that $f^{-1}[T] = U \cap M$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}[S] &= f^{-1}[\Bbb{R}^m \setminus T] = M \setminus f^{-1}[T] \\
&= M \setminus (U \cap M) = M \setminus U = M \cap (\Bbb{R}^n \setminus U).
\end{align*}
Note that $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus U$ is closed, as $U$ is open, proving $f^{-1}[S]$ is closed in $M$... But thats the problem we can't use this because our f has the closed property....

Comment: @Analysis_Mark In that proof, $f$ is assumed to have the open property, and I'm trying to establish it has the closed property as well. If you want to go the other direction, as I said, just swap the words "open" and "closed".

Comment: So you proved if M is an open subset of R^n then $f:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is continuous if and only the inverse image of all closed subsets of R^m is closed in M. I still don't understand how to get the result that if M is closed subset of R^n, then $f:M\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is continuous iff .... are closed in M. Also if f^(-1)(S) is closed in M, it is probably closed too in $\mathbb{R^n}$ right?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark I didn't assume $M$ is open or closed. The "Note: ..." paragraph was just showing that these new results, without assumptions that $M$ is open or closed, become the old results if you additionally assume $M$ is open or closed, but no such assumption is made while proving these new results.